# React Places Autocomplete handleChange error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am trying to configure https://github.com/hibiken/react-places-autocomplete#readme and when it comes to handleChange and handleSelect it throws an error

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (23:16):

  21 |     return true;
  22 |   }
> 23 |   handleChange = address => {
     |                ^
  24 |     this.setState({ address });
  25 |   };
  26 |
```

so therefore I change the syntax and make it to something like this thinking this would work,

```
handleChange(address){
    this.setState({ 
      address: address,
    });
  };

  handleSelect(address){
    geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then(latLng => console.log('Success', latLng))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error', error));
  };
```

and then says "**this.setState is not a function at Object.handleChange [as onChange]**"? Am I missing something here, can someone point me in the right direction! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post the body of the component where you define `handleChange`. You most probably haven't bound the function to your component like Siddiq said, hence you're trying to access the `setState` in a different context.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the function to `this` in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  ...
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

If you don't want to bind functions to `this`, use arrow functions instead.

```
this.handleChange = address => {
  this.setState({ address });
};
```

Or you can add classProperties support using this babel plugin: `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`